# Unable to show my images in PowerPoint Ribbon

Tags: vba, powerpoint, ribbonx

I have a customized ribbon in Excel and I want to replicate it in Power Point. I thought that the most difficult part would be addapting the macros, but I came across another problem: I cannot get my images to show in the ribbon. In the code below, both "my_image1" and "my_image2" show fine in Excel, but not in PP.

I have several images integrated into the file (using the Custon UI Editor) and it works perfectly in Excel. But in Power Point none of the images is shown.

I read that images need to be loaded before using them (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)) but I really do not get it.

```
    <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
<tabs>
            <tab id="customTab" label="My Ribbon"> <!--insertBeforeMso="TabHome"-->
<group id="Group1" label="Group 1">
<gallery
  id="Gallery1"
  label="Gallery 1"
  columns="3"
  rows="3"
  image="my_image1"
  showItemLabel="false"
  size="large"
  onAction="Insert_image"
  itemHeight="60"
  itemWidth="120"
  screentip=" " 
  supertip=" " >
      <item id="image01" label="Image 01" screentip="image description"  image="my_image2" />

Etc...
```

Could someone help with this issue? Do I need to include some other VBA code? I could not find any straightforward anwser for this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: I tested and it works fine, *however*: The way the Ribbon works, the names are *case-sensitive*, so make sure the spelling and *capitalization* matches exactly the file name you upload using the Custom UI Editor! But do *NOT* include the file extension (which you don't in the XML you show, but is recommended in an Answer). Also, these must be **png** files, not jpeg.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this but the problem was that my file was saved as "Presentation.pptm" and not "Presentation.ppam". Now that I have, I can see the images with no problem BUT now I cannot see the code to modify it. Is there any way to see and work with the VBA code of the add-in file?

Comment: This should also work in a pptm - my test file was a pptm. You cannot edit the code of a ppam file. Work with the pptm until everything is "perfect" then save as a ppam for the add-in. The only restriction is that the button will only be available in the pptm, not other presentations. So if you need to test the macro on other presentations you'll need to do it without the button...

Answer (score 2):

The Ribbon XML code looks good. I don't see anything strange in your code.

I'd suggest checking the following points:

- The recommended file format is PNG. Try to use them if you don't use them for ribbon controls.
- Make sure images are accessible and available in the file.
- Make sure there are no ribbon UI errors are displayed when the file is opened. To view any errors that your XML markup generates when it is loaded, follow these steps:

  1. Click the File tab, and then click Options.
  2. Click Advanced.
  3. Under Developers, select Show add-in user interface errors.
  4. Click OK to save your changes.

Read more about that in the [How to: Show Add-in user interface errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors?view=vs-2019) article.

Finally, you can declare a ribbon callback `getImage` for getting the image. In that scenario, you will be able to see what happens in the code. Because your code is responsible for loading and locating images.

Comment: Thank you! All these are great advices. The problem was that my file was saved as "Presentation.pptm" and not "Presentation.ppam" -- I guess that there's a restriction for pptm files. The problem now is that I cannot see the code to modify it. Is there any way to see and work with the VBA code of the add-in file? Or do I need to work in another file and then save it as add-in?